# Traduzione di "Unlinkability"

Tags: translation

Sto conducendo una ricerca sulla criptovaluta Monero e mi sono imbattuto in questi due termini che si riferiscono alle sue caratteristiche principali:

> **Untraceability**: for each incoming transaction all possible senders are
> equiprobable.
>
> **Unlinkability**: for any two outgoing transactions it is
> impossible to prove they were sent to the same person.

Se la prima penso si possa tradurre con "Intracciabilità", non mi viene in mente nessuna parola per la seconda caratteristica. Voi come la tradurreste (possibilmente con un unico termine)?

Comment: Domanda interessante. Metto queste proposte come commento, perché non ne sono del tutto convinto neppure io: “incollegabilità” o “inconnettibilità”, che non suonano benissimo, ma neanche i termini inglesi sono proprio il massimo (per quanto utili e abbastanza chiari).

Comment: Io preferirei “Non tracciabilità” per la prima e “Non attribuibilità” per la seconda. Anche queste sono ipotesi...

Comment: Per la seconda si potrebbe anche utilizzare “Non associabilità”

Comment: Giusto, anche il concetto di “associabilità” sembra pertinente.

Comment: C’è comunque parecchio materiale in italiano disponibile in rete che parla di Monero, dovesse servire: https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=pXRVW7nML4LQkwWC95eoCA&q=monero+ctyptovaluts&oq=monero+ctyptovaluts&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i13.13717.16840..17741...1.0...154.1310.2j9......0....1.........0i71j0i8i13i10i30j30i10.hA70XG8NfSs

Comment: Link un po' generico ma grazie lo stesso asd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Io tradurrei **Untraceability** con “**Non tracciabilità**” e **Unlinkability** con “**Non associabilità**”, visto che il link tra oggetti in ambito informatico è normalmente tradotto con associazione.

Comment: Mi piace come proposta, anche perché mi sono reso conto che, a quanto sembra, "intracciabilità" non esiste come parola ma, appunto, si dice "non tracciabilità".